# What does the word "retrieving" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, verbs

Please help me figure out the meaning of the word "retrieving" in the following sentence from the description of the game MudRunner Mobile:

> You’ll make a delivery by night, where obstacles are not easy to spot,
> and hop between vehicles – **retrieving** materials in one truck to repair
> another that you’ll fill up to refuel a gas-guzzling third.

I found the lexical meanings of the word "[retrieve](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retrieve)" here, but am not sure which of them fits here.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/retrieve In this, the seventh one sounds the most appropriate and fit for the situation.

Answer (score 1):

**Retrive** in this sentence means that you will use the first truck to get materials to fix the second one.

Comment: No, it does not. To _retrieve_ something is to fetch it back from somewhere.

Comment: so why isn't my sentece true, i don't understand... i fetch a piece from a truck and I use it on another truck. What's the difference?

Comment: Because "and use this part to fix another truck" is not part of the meaning of _retrieve_.

Comment: The passage says 'retrieving materials _in_ one truck', not 'taking parts from one truck'. I take it that the first truck is used to make a journey to collect the materials.

Comment: You are right @KateBunting, now i got it and edited the Answer